# Decode image from base64 to jpg

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, socket.io, base64

I am capturing an image on one client and sending the image to another client via socket.io to be sent out to users as a jpg. On the client capturing the image I am doing :

```
fs.readFile('./app/image.jpg', function(err, buf) {
      socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
})
```

This part is working fine and is encoding the image and emiting it. On the other client I have :

```
socket.on('image', function(img) {
            console.log(img);
});
```

This client is receiving the message and can log out the encoded image.

I am struggling converting the image from base64 to a jpg again. What do I need to do in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
socket.on('image', function(img) {
   var buffer = new Buffer(img, 'base64');
   // Now you probably want to save it as a file...
});
```